# Having problems with formdata.append()

Tags: javascript, form-data

I'm trying to upload file with form data. So I append image data to formdata object. But I keep getting error: `The laptop image field is required.`
(Spelling of 'laptop_image' is correct).

I also had to append some other data and they worked just fine

```
const fileInput = document.getElementById('laptop_image');

async function handleFormSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const form = document.querySelector('form');
    const url = form.action;

    try {
        const formData = new FormData(form);
        formData.append('laptop_image', fileInput.files[0]);

        const responseData = await postFormDataAsJson({ url, formData});
        console.log({ responseData });
    } catch (error) {
//also console.log(fileInput.files[0]); logs an image object
        console.error(error);
    }
}

form.addEventListener("submit", handleFormSubmit);
```

What am I doing wrong? :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't provided `postFormDataAsJson`, but we can make some assumptions about what it does.

You can't easily serialise a FormData object to JSON. `JSON.stringify` will convert it to an empty object.

```js
const fd = new FormData();
fd.append("key", "value");
const json = JSON.stringify(fd);
console.log(`JSON: ${json}`);
```

While there are ways to loop through the data in a FormData object to produce JSON from it:

- This largely renders using a FormData object pointless
- JSON still doesn't have a "File" data type

Generally, if you want to upload files + other data, you need to send multipart form data. The Ajax APIs built into browsers will serialise FormData objects to that format automatically.

```
fetch(url, { method: "POST", body: fd });
```

Of course, you need to send data in a format that the HTTP server is expecting (and we don't know anything about the one you are posting the data to).